# XMPP Smack chat using openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

Few questions around getting Chat working with Smack (3.2.1)/Openfire(3.7.1Alpha).

I am currently testing it using a unit test. My unit test creates a connection, creates account, logs in, adds a new user to its roster, *attempts* to send a chat message to the new user and eventually deletes the users. Apart from my confusions around getting chat to work, others seem to work (verified using openfire admin dashboard).

**A.** When I do the following

```
public void sendChatMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message) {     
    Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(receiver, messageListener);     
    chat.sendMessage(message);
}
```

Current connection is of the 'sender' (i.e. sender is logged in) and my attempt is to send a message to 'receiver'. When I get callback in my listener, message.getFrom() returns the 'receiver' and message.getBody() returns null. I am obviously trying to send a message on behalf of 'sender' to 'receiver'. What am I missing?

**B.** My 'sender' and 'receiver' are simply unique 'usernames' (without
    any @domain) and my server is simply 'localhost'.

```
connection = new XMPPConnection("localhost");
```

Do I need to modify the 'receiver' to be of different value to make it a valid JID (there are no errors at the moment)? What if I change my server (& the openfire server configurations)?

**C.** I am assuming there will always be one XMPPConnection per user? Is this correct?

**D.**

```
XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
```

When I have XMPPConnection in debug mode, a new window opens up, however, it is tied with my IDE. How can I have it not tied to the ide so I can look into the logs while trying to debug the code?

Comment: A: I think I misunderstood how it really worked. When someone sends me a message, processMessage in the listener receives it where from I can process it further. 

B. user@localhost seems to work alright.

C. I think it makes sense that each user opens one connection to the openfire.

D. Don't try it with unit-tests. It worked ok when I had a proper client connect to the server.

Comment: I have more questions as I still don't think I understand this fully. If all Openfire does is 'let me know' that a message has arrived, can I not simply store all the messages being received/sent in the db and I send them to appropriate receiver myself (which I need to do anyway as openfire doesn't actually send a message for me - I am not using any additional plugins). Still baffled!!!

Comment: can you please add some tutorial  or example on how to do this ? i'm also creating 1 app android with has a group chat functionality... i m using this apis but not able to receive the msgs.